# Multiple tables SQL with 1 same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
acco_info
acco_revenue_2016
```

Both tables have different columns except for 1, acco_id.
This column is what connects both tables.

I want to write a query that combines important data from both tables and links them to the `acco_id`.

So from the acco_info table I need the following columns:

```
acco_id, acco_name, region_name, country_name
```

From the acco_revenue_2016 table I need:

```
acco_id, sales, revenue_per_item, revenue
```

The output should look like this:

```
acco_id, acco_name, region_name, country_name, sales, revenue_per_item, revenue
```

What's the best way to write this query?
I am stuck on

```
SELECT acco_id FROM acco_info UNION SELECT acco_id FROM acco_revenue_2016
```

This joins the ID's together but I can't find a way to also show the other data.

Comment: You're looking for a JOIN rather than UNION i believe.

Comment: Thanks, JOIN indeed did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be looking for something like this;

```
SELECT
     ai.acco_id
    ,ai.acco_name
    ,ai.region_name
    ,ai.country_name
    ,ar.sales
    ,ar.revenue_per_item
    ,ar.revenue
FROM acco_info ai
INNER JOIN acco_revenue_2016 ar
    ON ai.acco_id = ar.acco_id
```

This is assuming that both tables contain the same acco_id. Notice the table aliases to see which field is coming from each table